# RouterLink set isActive by two routes

Tags: angular

I have a navigation that works as following:

```
- user
- products
  + category1
  + category2
```

Navigating to products based on the URL further navigates per default to `category1`.

I have implemented this with a `mat-tab-nav-bar` where the main tab is highlighted for User when the route is `/user` and highlighted for Products when the route is `/products/category1` (as it is navigated there per default).

Within the products I have two buttons for category1 and category2, which navigate to `/products/category1` and `/products/category2`, respectively.

I want the main tab Products to be highlighted, no matter if category1 or category2 is set. The problem is, that whenever I switch to category2, the main tab is not highlighted anymore.

**Typescript:**

```
this.routes = [
{
  name: 'User',
  path: '/user',
  index: 0
}, {
  name: 'Products',
  path: '/products/category1',
  index: 1
}];
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let route of routes"
     [routerLink]="route.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive" >
    {{route.name}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you try adding the option: `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }"` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9578#issuecomment-264736633

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it works when using

```
path: ['/products', subCategory]',
```

where subCategory is a variable holding either 'category1' or 'category2' as value, based on the path of the url that is registered by the router.